# android app not installed when directly share with share it even after generating key

Tags: android

Please help me I cannot be able to install my app on my friend mobile directly by sharing with share it . I have generate keystore properly all necessary step follow but still it cannot be shared. But when I publish on beta testing, it is easily installed on my friend mobile, I want to share directly with share it. Please help me

Comment: What is the error while installing the apk ?

Comment: id response 3 error occur. I am disable google play protect but still app cannot be installed .Please help me .

Comment: thanks i solved this error